# Question about tax deduction in a specific country are off topic?

Tags: discussion

This is the *incriminated* question.

One user correctly says that the question is really specific and that it's not so sure that can be considered about expatriates.

https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/270/tax-deduction-in-austria

My reasonment was the following: "I've expatriate to Austria. So now I've to deal with it's laws. This means I'll have to learn languages, care about retirement, care about it's law, care about the fines, and of course about the taxes. And this happens because I expatriate there and for no other reason.."

What's your opinion on that?